# How to replace a Matplotlib axis with a curvilinear axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis, figure

There's a nice example of a curvilinear axis grid in the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/axisartist/demo_curvelinear_grid.html).  This assumes you have an empty figure and then you create the curvilinear axis using:

```
ax1 = Subplot(fig, 1, 2, 1, grid_helper=grid_helper)
```

However, I am writing a function that is given an existing axis and I want the function to replace this axis (`ax`) with the new curvilinear axis.

Here is the start of my function so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist import SubplotHost
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.grid_helper_curvelinear import GridHelperCurveLinear
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist.angle_helper as angle_helper
from matplotlib.projections import PolarAxes
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

def sgrid(ax=None):
    """
    Adds an s-plane grid of constant damping factors and natural
    frequencies to a plot.  If ax is not specified, the current
    figure axis is used.

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax : matplotlib axis object
        If not passed, uses gca() to get current axis.

    Returns
    -------
    ax : matplotlib axis
    """

    grid_helper = GridHelperCurveLinear(
        ... some stuff ...
    )

    if ax is None:
        # Get the current axis or create a new figure with one
        ax = plt.gca()
    fig = ax.figure

    # TODO: How can we change the axis if it is already created?
    ax = SubplotHost(fig, 1, 1, 1, grid_helper=grid_helper)

    ... (code that adds more stuff to ax) ...

    return ax
```

Also, I'm not sure I understand the arguments to `SubplotHost`.  Are these the initialization arguments of a new Axis or what?

***UPDATE***

The goal here is to emulate the way Pandas.Series.plot functions work.  The desired use-cases are things like these:

```
H = tf([2, 5, 1],[1, 2, 3])
rlocus(H)
sgrid()
plt.show()
```

or

```
>>> fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1)
>>> rlocus(H1, ax=axes[1])
>>> rlocus(H2, ax=axes[2])
>>> for ax in axes:
>>>     sgrid(ax=ax)  # Later we might want to add ax.zgrid()
>>> plt.show()
```

The order of `sgrid` and `rlocus` should ideally be as above as this is similar to the MATLAB functions we are emulating and also the `plt.grid()` method which these are similar to.

Comment: Do you need to leave the original axes in place (possibly with some artists already present), or would you be OK with destroying the original axes and replacing it with the new one at the same location?

Comment: You cannot change the existing axes to suddenly become a different axes; so you need to know the parameters upfront and then create this axes.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I would be happy to destroy the existing axis and re-create it.  The goal here is to model the behaviour of other functions which have only an axis argument (similar to Pandas.Sereis.plot etc).  Rather than having to pass a figure instead.  I will add an example of the desired use cases.

Comment: Does anyone know what method/class is actually using the `grid_helper`?  I'm struggling to trace where `SubplotHost` eventually sends this argument in the Matplotlib documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid_helper` is a keyword for `mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines.Axes`.
https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines.html

You might want to check if the provided axis is a subclass of this Axes extension and recreate the axis otherwise:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist import SubplotHost,axislines

...

def sgrid(ax1=None):
    ...
    if ax1 is None:
        ax1=plt.gca()
    fig=ax1.figure
    if not isinstance(ax1,axislines.Axes):
        subargs=ax1.get_geometry()
        fig.delaxes(ax1)
        ax2 = SubplotHost(fig, *subargs, grid_helper=grid_helper)
        fig.add_subplot(ax2)
    else:
       ax2=ax1
    ...

    return ax2
```

Be aware that the caller of `sgrid()` still references `ax1` which is no longer part of the figure. There might be a more sophisticated replacement of the axes references necessary than to just delete and recreate.

Comment: This is great!  Thanks.  And it seems to work now that I have implemented it.  I like the idea of returning the new axis (`ax2`) but it would be really nice if the method could update the original figure's reference to it (i.e. in `figure.axes`).  I suppose that's not possible or problematic.

Comment: Did you consider the use of `Axes.add_child_axes()`  or `Axes.inset_axes()` or something similar? You could link the bounds and limits using `sharex=` and `sharey=` as well as layer it behind the parent axis.

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  I will check it out.  Should I be worried about the fact that it says "This method is experimental as of 3.0, and the API may change." on the documentation page?